# Android - simple app to adding content into listview by edittext

Tags: android

I'm trying to do simple application in android to adding content by editText into listView ... And I don't know what is wrong, why it don't work.. I do it by tutorial from YouTube, step by step and when app is run and I click button to add content, and it dont't work ... it should be new row added but I have nothing. Please help !

YT source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8NAavE5HDWk

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btn_add;
private EditText edit_Work, edit_Hour, edit_Minute;
private ListView lv_List;
private ArrayList<Item> array;
private ArrayAdapter<Item> adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn_add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Add);
    edit_Work = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_work);
    edit_Hour = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_hour);
    edit_Minute = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_minute);
    lv_List = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_list);
    lv_List.setAdapter(adapter);

    array = new ArrayList<Item>();
    adapter = new Adapter(this, R.layout.custom_listview, array);

    btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AddWork();
        }
    });
}

public void AddWork()
{
    if(edit_Work.getText().toString().equals("") || edit_Hour.getText().toString().equals("") || edit_Minute.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Info Missing");
        builder.setMessage("Please add info ...");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
    }
    else
    {
        final String work = edit_Work.getText().toString();
        final String time = edit_Hour.getText().toString() + "h :" + edit_Minute.getText().toString() + "'";
        Item item = new Item(work, time);
        array.add(0, item);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        edit_Work.setText("");
        edit_Hour.setText("");
        edit_Minute.setText("");
        edit_Work.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

}

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

private Activity context;
private int id;
ArrayList<Item> array;


public Adapter(Activity context, int resource, ArrayList<Item> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context=context;
    this.id=resource;
    this.array=objects;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView=inflater.inflate(id,null);
    }
    final Item item = array.get(position);
    TextView txtWork = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_work);
    TextView txtTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_time);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbx_work);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            item.setChecked(isChecked);
        }
    });

    txtWork.setText(item.getWork());
    txtTime.setText(item.getTime());
    checkBox.setChecked(item.isChecked());

    return convertView;
}
```

}

```
public class Item {
private String work;
private String time;
private boolean isChecked;

public Item(String work, String time)
{
    this.work = work;
    this.time = time;
    isChecked = false;
}

public String getWork() {
    return work;
}

public void setWork(String work) {
    this.work = work;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public boolean isChecked() {
    return isChecked;
}

public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    isChecked = checked;
}
```

}

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/work"
    android:textSize="30dp" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_work"
    android:hint="Add My Name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hour"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_hour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="12"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColorHint="#ccc"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/minute"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_minute"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="00"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColorHint="#ccc"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_Add"
    android:text="@string/add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ListView>
```

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:background="#ccc"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_work"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cbx_work"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: may not be the issue but array.add(0, item) will replace the object at position 0 in the arraylist, not necessarily create a new line.  maybe try array.add(item) to append a new object to the end of the list.

Comment: That is incorrect. It's an array list and the list reorganizes the rest of indices to place that element on the desired spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed several things in your code and I will try to explain what I fixed and why. I tested the code and it works perfectly fine now.

First: Rename `Adapter` class to `MyAdapter` or something similar. When you are using custom classes always try to use a unique name. There already is an (abstract) Adapter class and it is unclear which one you will use. That's why it's important to define a unique name, not already taken by the system.

The same goes for `Item`, as there is a class `Item` in the system.

Second: You have to call `mAdapter = new MyAdapter(...)` first and only then assign it to a ListView via `listview.setAdapter(mAdapter)`.

Third: change `private ArrayAdapter<Item> adapter;` to `private MyAdapter mAdapter`

Always try to keep your variable and class names unique. A common convention is to use `m` + `VariableType` writing style for your variables (for example `mAdapter`) and you will see it a lot in Google's code and developer guides.